# Dynamic labels and scoring via +1 and -1 buttons with tk

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to populate a list of webpages that can be accessed if clicked from a tk interface. Each link should have next to it a counter that can be updated using the +1 and -1 button; all on one line. So it should look like:
linkl1 counter +1button -1button

linkl2 counter +1button -1button

linkl3 counter +1button -1button etc....

I have 2 problems I cannot solve: 1- clicking on the links do not get open in a browser 2- clicking on the +1 or -1 button does not update the link counter.
Could anyone help me, please? Here is the code:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

class TestClass:
    counter = {}
    root = tk.Tk()

    def __init__(self):
        self.root.title('Test')

        self.topframe = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.topframe.pack( side = tk.TOP, pady=30)

        self.bottomframe = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.bottomframe.pack( side = tk.BOTTOM )

        self.button = tk.Button(self.topframe, text='Click', command = self.output_value)
        self.button.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def callback(event):
        webbrowser.open_new(event.widget.cget("text"))

    def plus1(self,url):
        self.counter[url] = int(self.counter[url]) + 1
        self.DisplayButton["text"]=str(self.counter[url])

    def neg1(self,url):
        self.counter[url] = int(self.counter[url]) - 1
        self.DisplayButton["text"]=str(self.counter[url])


 ####define the function that the submit button will do
    def output_value(self):
        urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.facebook.com"]
        i=0
        for url in urls:
            self.counter[url] = random.randint(1, 10)
            lbl = tk.Label(self.bottomframe, text=url, fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
            lbl.grid(row=i, column=1)
            lbl.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)

            self.DisplayButton = tk.Button(self.bottomframe, text = self.counter[url])
            self.DisplayButton.grid(row=i, column=2)
            self.DisplayButton.config(height = 1, width = 1 )

            self.Plus1Button = tk.Button(self.bottomframe, text = "+1", command=self.plus1(url), bg="green")
            self.Plus1Button.grid(row=i, column=3)
            self.Plus1Button.config(height = 1, width = 1 )

            self.Neg1Button = tk.Button(self.bottomframe, text = "-1", command=self.neg1(url), bg="green")
            self.Neg1Button.grid(row=i, column=4)
            self.Neg1Button.config(height = 1, width = 1 )
            i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestClass()
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the counter work you need to use `functools.partial` to make a "closure" to use as the command.

```
from functools import partial
#...
self.Plus1Button = tk.Button(self.bottomframe, text = "+1", command=partial(self.plus1, url), bg="green")
```

To make the url open work you just need to read the error message. You are missing an argument in the callback function. Try:

```
def callback(self, event):
    webbrowser.open_new(event.widget.cget("text"))
```

Comment: The callback works, but there is still an issue with the counter. Clicking on the button only update the displayvalue of the last item. Not on a line by line fascion.

Comment: @Pierre I know; you update the last made Button. You could pass the Button along with the url; or you could use a class instead of that dictionary like I show in my other answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunately the systems does not allow me to increase the feedback score, because I am new. But I highly value your support!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a group of data and functions that fit into a logical group (a line) ... this should scream at you that it should be it's own class. It would be much neater like this:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

class Pierre:
    """This class holds all the objects, data and functions for a single line"""
    def __init__(self, master, url):
        self.url = url
        self.counter = 0
        _, i = master.grid_size() # get the current row number

        lbl = tk.Label(master, text=url, fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
        lbl.grid(row=i, column=1)
        lbl.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)

        self.DisplayButton = tk.Button(master, text = self.counter)
        self.DisplayButton.grid(row=i, column=2)
        self.DisplayButton.config(height = 1, width = 1 )

        self.Plus1Button = tk.Button(master, text = "+1", command=self.plus1, bg="green")
        self.Plus1Button.grid(row=i, column=3)
        self.Plus1Button.config(height = 1, width = 1 )

        self.Neg1Button = tk.Button(master, text = "-1", command=self.neg1, bg="green")
        self.Neg1Button.grid(row=i, column=4)
        self.Neg1Button.config(height = 1, width = 1 )

    def plus1(self):
        self.counter += 1
        self.DisplayButton["text"]=str(self.counter)

    def neg1(self):
        self.counter -= 1
        self.DisplayButton["text"]=str(self.counter)

    def callback(self, event):
        webbrowser.open_new(self.url)

class TestClass(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.title('Test')

        self.topframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.topframe.pack( side = tk.TOP, pady=30)

        self.bottomframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.bottomframe.pack( side = tk.BOTTOM )

        self.button = tk.Button(self.topframe, text='Click', command = self.output_value)
        self.button.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

 ####define the function that the submit button will do
    def output_value(self):
        urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.facebook.com"]
        for url in urls:
            Pierre(self.bottomframe, url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = TestClass()
    root.mainloop()
```

Also, you should not define class variables (variables that are in a class but not in a method) like that. In fact stay away from class variables entirely until you understand the very rare situations where they are useful.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @Novel method is to use data binding and let the button automatic update its text if the bounded variable changes for some reason.

```
class Pierre:
    """This class holds all the objects, data and functions for a single line"""
    def __init__(self, master, url):
        self.url = url
        self.counter = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        _, i = master.grid_size() # get the current row number

        lbl = tk.Label(master, text=url, fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
        lbl.grid(row=i, column=1)
        lbl.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)

        self.DisplayButton = tk.Button(master, textvariable = self.counter)
        self.DisplayButton.grid(row=i, column=2)
        self.DisplayButton.config(height = 1, width = 1 )

        self.Plus1Button = tk.Button(master, text = "+1", command=self.plus1, bg="green")
        self.Plus1Button.grid(row=i, column=3)
        self.Plus1Button.config(height = 1, width = 1 )

        self.Neg1Button = tk.Button(master, text = "-1", command=self.neg1, bg="green")
        self.Neg1Button.grid(row=i, column=4)
        self.Neg1Button.config(height = 1, width = 1 )

    def plus1(self):
        self.counter.set(self.counter.get() + 1)

    def neg1(self):
        self.counter.set(self.counter.get() - 1)

    def callback(self, event):
        webbrowser.open_new(self.url)
```